# Can `nil` be matched on a `case/when` statement, with an explicit `when nil` branch?

Tags: ruby, null, switch-statement

I have a Ruby `case/when` statement, which takes different options for a parameter.

There are three valid cases: symbols, integers, and nil; anything else is invalid.

In the most obvious form, there are four cases:

```rb
case param
when Symbol
  run_symbol_code
when Integer
  run_integer_code
when nil
  # do nothing
else
  raise_error
end
```

now, I was wondering: is there any way to avoid the `nil` case? Originally I thought about:

```rb
case param
when Symbol
  run_symbol_code
when Integer
  run_integer_code
when Object
  raise_error
end
```

however, this doesn't work, because nil is actually an object. There's also the option to use `raise_error if param` in the last case, but I don't find it very appealing.

Is there any way to use only three cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this in which `nil` results in *do nothing* I would prefer a [Guard Clause](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/GuardClause) because it is easy to read and understand.

```
def method(param)
  return if param.nil?

  case param
  when Symbol
    run_symbol_code
  when Integer
    run_integer_code
  else
    raise_error
  end
end
```

Of course, it doesn't reduce the number of checks.

Comment: I think this reads best. Another option is to deal with the `nil` case even earlier: `ret_val = method(param) unless param.nil?`.

Answer (score 1):

In ruby you can add condition at the end of `case`, `iterators` statements.

like following

```
case param
when Symbol
  run_symbol_code
when Integer
  run_integer_code
else
  raise_error
end unless param.nil?
```

Note:- `end unless param.nil?` in such cases 'case', `iterator` will run only when condition permits i.e `Case` will run only when param is not nil.

Comment: That seems to be cleaner than solution I suggested. One minor caveat is that I'd prefer to see that check before the switch statement (as some kind of guard), but hey, nothing is perfect.

Comment: @raina77ow Of course we can use `return` statement if we are using `case` at the end of the method. But if there is any code which we want to rub after the case staement we can use `case...end unless param.nil?`